# How to click on an hidden drop down menu element using webdriver, which is not a select

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I want to click on delete which is in the sub menu.

I tried the below code, but nothing happens.

```
wd_handle.execute_script("document.getElementById('optionPanel').hidden=false;")
mouse.move_to_element(OptionPanel).perform()
WebDriverWait(wd_handle,10)
wd_handle.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Delete').click()
```

## HTML Source:

```
<div id="optionPanel" style="height: auto; width: auto; left: 126px; top: 368px; display: none; overflow-y: hidden;">'
 <div class="wrapper">
  <ul aria-hidden="false" role="menu">
   <li role="menuitem">
   <li role="menuitem">
   <li class="divider" role="menuitem">
    <a class="optionPanelLink" tabindex="0" 
    href="#playlistManager/action=delete/selected=701f55af-c5f0-4f31-b34f-964f52be5fef/idx=0">
    Delete</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have to click on the element with id = 7ba9b231-5fc4-448b-b41a-f236437c182cCount to make the above elements visible.

```
<li class="playlist viewing"> 
<a id="7ba9b231-5fc4-448b-b41a-f236437c182cLink" class="ellipsis" title="TestList2" href="#playList/name=TestList2/list=7ba9b231-5fc4-448b-b41a-f236437c182c">TestList2</a> 
<span class="entryCount">0</span> 
<a id="7ba9b231-5fc4-448b-b41a-f236437c182cCount" class="customPlaylistSpriteLocation optionSprite" href="#option/playlist=TestList2/selected=7ba9b231-5fc4-448b-b41a-f236437c182c/idx=0"></a> 
</li>
```

Comment: Write the xpath for that and then try to execute. Hope it should work.

Comment: Since its not in the select tag, try to handle it with normal click operations

Comment: I have tried using the normal click operation using all possible locators but it did not work. :( I'm struck

Comment: Wait, so is the initial click on the element with ID not working either?

Answer (score 5):

You can click on the hidden menu item using xpath

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
   Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
   builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Enter Menu here"))).build().perform();
  builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Enter Target here"))).build().perform();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("Enter Target here")).click()
```

Hope this is code do

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `find_element_by_partial_link_text('Delete')` works and return an element ?

If it really doesn't work i suggest to use the cssSelector like : `"li.divider a"`

Tell me what's up.

Comment: I have tried that, but it could not find that element. I am wondering if the element is still hidden after clicking on id = 7ba9b231-5fc4-448b-b41a-f236437c182cCount

Comment: @user2008902 if you can't find it, that's because your element is hidden and the driver works like a guy how want to click on somethink that he can't find. you see my point ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
wd_handle.execute_script("document.getElementById('optionPanel').hidden=false;")
```

With:

```
wd_handle.execute_script("document.getElementById('optionPanel').style.display='block';")
```

If it doesn't work, then try using both of them (one after another)...

Answer (score -1):

First of all check your submenu item in which place delete button is highlighted......by using hover.And take that as a reference  w.r.t id you can click delete button...here is a code

```
WebElement wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@datapostid='52f377a10a1de86e33f9bc90']/div"));
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(wb);
        act.perform();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wb.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.commdelete")).click();
```